# PostSharp: Exclude multicasted attribute from classes within same namespace that derive from common base

Tags: c#, attributes, aop, postsharp, aspect

I'm multicasting an interface introduction at the assembly level over all EF entities in a given namespace, but I want to exclude from introduction any classes within that namespace that derive from DbContext.  Not sure how to do this without explicitly excluding each DbContext-derived class by name. :(

```
[assembly: MyApi.IntroduceAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "MyApi.Models.*")]
[assembly: MyApi.IntroduceAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "MyApi.Models.SomeContext", AttributeExclude = true)]
[assembly: MyApi.IntroduceAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "MyApi.Models.SomeOtherContext", AttributeExclude = true)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute multicasting doesn't allow to filter on the base class of the target type. For this kind of filtering you can implement `CompileTimeValidate` method in your aspect and return `false` if the target type derives from `DbContext`.

```
public override bool CompileTimeValidate(Type targetType) 
{
    if (typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Documentation link: http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-validation